# Asynchronously queue processing with RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I'm having problem finding good example of asynchronous queue processing in RabbitMQ.
I've tried to start implement something like this in server side:

```
//here I declare the connection exchange and queue
$this->connection = new AMQPConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$this->channel = $this->connection->channel();            
$this->channel->exchange_declare("exchange", 'direct', false, false, false);
list($this->queue_name, ,) = $this->channel->queue_declare("Queue", false, false, true, false);

while($envelope = $queue->get()) 
{
    // do work here...
}
```

The problem is I'm having the queue name returned instead of queue reference so I will be able to use it in the following `while` loop.

I've tried also to create and declare  a queue as in written in [this link](http://www.brandonsavage.net/publishing-messages-to-rabbitmq-with-php/) but I don't have class such as `AMQPQueue` in my `RabbitMQ` delivered package.

Somebody know how to get queue instance for being able to use the [get](http://docs.php.net/manual/pt_BR/amqpqueue.get.php) method?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using this library: https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib

Take a look at this example: https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/demo/amqp_consumer.php

And also: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html